# Cannot find symbol using BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm doing my first attempts to use BigDecimal. It seems tricky.i am running into an issue and i would like to understand what is causing it.

```
public static String nominator(String nbrPeople)
{
    BigDecimal nom = new BigDecimal("365") ;
    BigDecimal days = new BigDecimal("365") ;
    int limit = Integer.parseInt(nbrPeople);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ )
    {
        days = days.substract(i) ;
        nom = nom.multiply(days) ;
    }
    return  nbrPeople ;
}
```

this is part of a larger program. it is a method that should compute something like this:

365 x (365-1) x (365-2) x (365-3) etc depending on the value of nbrPeople passed in.

i would like to understand why i get the following error message:

> cannot find symbol
>
> method substract(int)

not looking for a discussion on factorials but rather on the use of BigDecimal (or BigInteger). I'm using BigDecimal because at a later stage i will need to divide, resulting in floating point.

**EDIT**

**EDIT 2**

first edit removed (code) to make the post more readable- the correct code has been posted below by a kind programmer

Comment: As already mentioned in my answer. You cant subtract i because it is not a BigInteger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static String nominator(String nbrPeople)
{
    BigDecimal nom = new BigDecimal("365") ;
    BigDecimal days = new BigDecimal("365") ;
    int limit = Integer.parseInt(nbrPeople);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ )
    {
        days = days.subtract(new BigDecimal(i)) ;
        nom = nom.multiply(days) ;
    }
    return  nbrPeople ;
}
```

as there is no `BigDecimal.subtract(int)` method, only a `BigDecimal.subtract(BigDecimal)` method.

Comment: @ALL: Thanks for your prompt responses. It all make more sense now!

Comment: Funny that you made the same typo - "substract" for "subtract".

Comment: Copy & Paste and not noticing.

Answer (score 5):

Because the method is named subtract not substract.

And the parameter has to be BigInteger too:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#subtract(java.math.BigInteger)

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to subtract an `int` from a `BigDecimal`. Since there is no method `subtract(int x)` on the `BigDecimal` class, you get the `cannot find symbol` compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Typo - you misspelled "subtract".

Answer (score 1):

Should be [subtract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#subtract%28java.math.BigInteger%29) ( with a single s )

Whenever you see *cannot find symbol* message, you are trying to use a method that doesn't exist or a variable that doesn't exists. Most of the time ( as in this case ) due to a misspelling or because you didn't import the class.

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal can only subtract another BigDecimal.  you are subtracting an int.  See

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract(java.math.BigDecimal)

Answer (score 0):

*http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract(java.math.BigDecimal*

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigDecimal_SumExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BigDecimal  number1;
        BigDecimal  number2;
        BigDecimal  sum;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value of number 1");
        number1 = sc.nextBigDecimal();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of number 2");
        number2 = sc.nextBigDecimal();


        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(""+number1);
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(""+number2);
        BigDecimal result = a.add(b);

        System.out.println("Sum is Two numbers : -> ");
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}

**Output is** 

Enter the value of number 1
68237161328632187132612387312687321678312612387.31276781237812

Enter the value of number 2
31232178631276123786321712369812369823162319862.32789129819299

Sum is Two Big Decimal numbers : -> 
99469339959908310918934099682499691501474932249.64065911057111
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract(java.math.BigDecimal